# Double Harmonic (Ultraphrygian) Examples

Tags: scales, composition, modes, composers

Around 2 years ago i accidentally discovered Phrygian #3 #7 while jamming and found out with some research, that it apears to be called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale. Since then i am adicted to it and use it heavily in nearly all of my compositions.

I can not find any use of this scale (except a few metal bands). **Does anyone know composers/pieces that use this scale? I would like to get more input :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claude Debussy used it in some pieces, as did Richie Blackmore. Miles Davis used in Nardis. See the links hereunder for more pieces.

[Here](http://www.tonaltrends.com/double-harmonic-in-misirlou/4582471331) at the bottom are listed a few pieces, as well as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale) near the top.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its a little bit weird, that i missed the pieces in the wiki-article ;)

Answer (score 0):

(I would like only post a comment but I have no enough reputation for that.)

A similar question war raised in [Phrygian dominant scale with a major seventh](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33219/phrygian-dominant-scale-with-a-major-seventh). Matt L. answers that [Misirlou](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-y3h9p_c5-M) of Dick Dale us that scale.